How to test for equal variances of correlated observations?
Let $r$ be a vector valued random variable with mean zero and variance $\Omega$.
Let $r_t$ denote a specific observation of $r$ at time $t$.
$\Omega$ is unknown but I have 2 estimates of it: $\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b$. These estimates come from 2 different models/techniques fit on observed values of the random vector $r$, along with some other covariates.
Let $\Omega_{a, t}$ denote an estimate of $\Omega$ from model/technique $a$ and observations of $r$ up to but not including time $t$. Similar for $\Omega_{b, t}$.
I want to evaluate which of these are better estimates of covariance.
To do so, I define new random scalars.
$$y_a = x_a'r$$
$$y_b = x_b'r$$
where $x_a$ is the value of $x$ that minimizes $variance(a) = x'\Omega_a x$ subject to $sum(x) = 1$. Similarly for $x_b$.
$\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b$ are positive definite matrices so this minimization is convex optimization and there is a single global minimum.
Let $y_{a,t}$ denote an oservation of $y_a$ at time $t$, similar for $y_{b,t}$.
For each time period $t$, I estimate $\Omega_{a,t}$ and $\Omega_{b,t}$ using data from before $t$.
I then observe $r_t$, calculate $x_{a, t}$ and $x_{b, t}$, and ultimately measure $y_{a,t}$ and $y_{b,t}$.
Once I have iterated through all my data and I have a bunch of observations of $y_a$ and $y_b$, I can estimate their variances, $\sigma^2_a$ and $\sigma^2_b$ respectively.
If $\sigma^2_a$ is significantly lower than $\sigma^2_b$ then I conclude that model/technique $a$ is better than model/technique $b$, since achieving a low $\sigma^2$ requires choosing the best $x$ which requires a close estimate of $\Omega$.
If I assume this data is normally distributed (it has slightly fat tails actually) can I use the usual F test? I don't think so because $y_a$ and $y_b$ are not independent. The covariance between $y_a$ and $y_b$ is given by $x_a'\Omega x_b$, but this is not observable directly, since $\Omega$ is unknown.
There are other tests such as

Barletts test
Ansari test
Mood test
Fligner test

But it is not clear to me if any of these are appropriate for correlated data.
My ultimate goal is to be able to support or refute the null hypothesis that these 2 models/techniques produce equally good estimates of $\Omega$. Note that sample covariance is a very poor estimate since the dimension of the matrix is much much higher than the number of observations.

How do you estimate $\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b,$ based on what data? What is "$\Omega$" and how might it be, if at all, related to your data? How do $x_a$ and $x_b$ permit you to "observe" a random variable and how might that be related to the data you refer to earlier? In what sense are $a_t$ and $b_t$ scalars, when they depend on the index $t$? Exactly what might be normally distributed? Are you asking about the properties of two covariance estimators or how to evaluate in one circumstance which estimate might be better? How do you quantify what makes one estimate "better" than another?

Since you have many good questions, it might be better to update my original question to address these. I will do so now.

@whuber, I have tried to address your questions and improve the clarity. Let me know if this is any better and if there is more clarification required.

Thanks, but much of this remains mysterious.  If the models are different, why is it even possible to compare the two covariance estimates--don't they mean different things?  Suddenly, halfway through, time makes an appearance: how is that related to what preceded it?  Since it appears you have a whole time series of covariance estimates, what exactly are you trying to compare?  One gets the sense that lurking beneath this complicated procedure might be a statistical question that possibly is addressed through an entirely different approach.

@whuber, understood. I have added much more clarity and tried to be more formal about setting the scene on this.

@whuber, please let me know if this requires further clarification.

Here's a suggestion (I haven't studied it).  Under the null hypothesis, the variances will still be equal under any rotation of two variables.  So, apply a rotation in which the variables are uncorrelated (there always is one) and proceed from there.
